# Plesk: Accessing files without moving domain name first

Tags: dns, ip, plesk

I recently purchased a virtual server from Hetzner.de, and am trying to use it to upload my PHP & MySQL-site to. I've managed to make a database and upload my files to httpdocs, but I'd like to make sure everything is working before I point my domain name to it. I can't seem to access the files by typing the IP-address /index.php, and can't figure out another option. Does anyone know how to do this?

Also, does anyone happen to know a nice starter guide for Plesk?

Kind regards,
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access it through http://ipaddress/index.php if the server is running. You can point your domain name just to check, It wont take more than a day for it, in worst case just two days. Have you tried reaching the service provider? You can find various tutorials on youtube for introduction to plesk.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have tried accessing it this way, which did not work the first 3 days but it seems to work now. Many thanks!